# icon in datagrid context menu don't work

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add an icon to a datagrid context menu
however altough I added the file to the folder and changed it to copy always.

The context menu do not show the photo. insted he write the photo path:"Delete-icon.ico"
would be happy for an answer
thanks,

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGData" Grid.Column="2" PreviewKeyDown="DGData_PreviewKeyDown" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete"  Click="MenuItem_Click" Icon="Delete-icon.ico"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Icon` property to an `Image`:

```
<MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItem_Click">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="Delete-icon.ico" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```